# how to call function within a polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer

While reading the implementation of the `core-xhr` element by the Polymer team, the comments indicated that we could use the following method to use the element to perform XMLHttpRequests

```
* core-xhr can be used to perform XMLHttpRequests.
*
*     <core-xhr id="xhr"></core-xhr>
*     ...
*     this.$.xhr.request({url: url, params: params, callback: callback});
```

the request() method is declared within the polymer declaration as follow

```
Polymer('core-xhr', {
     request: function(options) {...},
     toQueryString: function(params) {....},
                ....
});
```

I will like to create a non-ui element where I could, using JavaScript, call on the methods declared within the non-ui element as demonstrated. It will seem that the method above was declared normally but I was unable to access my method.

My test element

```
<polymer-element name="test-element" attributes="url">
<template>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        url:"",
        alert: function()
        {
            alert("alert!");
        }           
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

My test page

```
<body>
    <test-element id = "test"></test-element> 
    <script>
       $('#test').alert();
    </script
</body>
```

I was given a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Does anyone know if I missed anything out or there was issue with how i called my alert method?

Thanks

Comment: what is your polymer version?

Comment: version 0.5.1 I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your trying to call the api on the jquery wrapper. Instead either use $('#test').get(0).alert() to get the element interface or even better make a direct call using document.querySelector("#test").alert()

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').get(0).alert();
  });

  // without jquery
  // document.querySelector("#test").alert()
```

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="test-element" attributes="url">
  <template>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      url: "",
      alert: function() {
        alert("alert!");
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<test-element id="test"></test-element>
```